# Send mail with values from returned SOAP request which is converted to json

Tags: php, json

I have a form that I am submitting via PHP cURL as SOAP to a WSDL. It submits fine, and my PHP handler takes the returned xml and converts it to a json string like this:

```
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $url2 );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
if ($result === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_errno($soap_do);
    print $err;
} else {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
    $body = $xml->xpath("//soapenv:Body//demosetupReturn")[0];
    $output = [];
    foreach ( $body as $item)  {
        $output[(string)$item->key] = (string)$item->value;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
curl_close($soap_do);
```

The returned data (xml/SOAP) is converted to a json string which looks like this:

```
{"DemoUName":"FBar308r","DemoPass":"Demo5538r","FutAcct":"DEMO06341r","FxAcct":"","UUID":"ED31DA3C-D015-4B7F-AAB2-0B6ECBF17FEr","Result":"User has been added with ID = 57218r Account DEMO06341r2 has been moved from User Pool to User FBar308r "}
```

I need to access the $output, and extract some values, say "DemoUName", "DemoPass" etc from it and stuff that into a php sendmail function. How do I access the json data items as PHP $var and send mail?

Comment: Don't encode it? Immediately decode it using `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the $output before it is converted to json.

```
$message = "Here are elements from the soap message captured:\n";
$message .= $output['DemoUName'] . "\n";
$message .= $output['DemoPass'] . "\n";
$to = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'soap capture';
mail($to, $subject, $message);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Just put the above in before the "echo json_encode($output);" line? No issue, I just use the json to trigger a js workflow in the $.ajax request

Comment: Indead, above the `echo json_encode($output)` is appropriate. You have to define a value for $to and $subject also of course.

Comment: This worked great, the only issue I'm having is accessing the $Email value that is submitted when someone fills out the form, since it isn't included in the returned data. I need to cc the $Email POST value

Answer (score 1):

The data is returned from the curl request as an object with name:value properties. If you wanted to echo out "DemoUName" you'd use

```
echo $var->DemoUName;
```

That's how you access object properties.

For the mailer, I'd send it off prior to encoding. Generally speaking, you can access the [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in php with something to the effect of:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

How you'll build your message is entirely up to you, but you can append your variables from the curl object to your $message var. Easy peasy way would be with something like...

`$message .= $var->DemoUName .', '. $var->otherProperty .', '. $var->otherOtherProperty .'.'`;

Comment: That looks good. No issue sending mail in PHP. I would do this before I do the "echo json_encode($output);" correct? I'd still like to convert it to json so my js routine will know what to do.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You're not changing $output to be json_encoded in this scope. You're only echoing out a json_encoded version of it. So using the $output variable at any point will be fine. UNLESS you do something like $output = json_encode($output);, $output does not actually change here.

Comment: Actually, misread your code a bit. You could just use $xml at any point in the code. You don't empty it. After you encode $object (which once again you're only echoing an encoded version), you can still access $xml and it will still contain the results of the request.